# Как прописать, чтобы Search Bar открывался при нажатии на короткий input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на input 200-300px открывалось целое поле, но при нажатии снова не закрывалось. Тоесть как прописать команду, чтобы оно открылось, но допустим пользователь ткул случайно ещё раз и оно не закрывалось, а оставалось во всю длину.

Comment: есть в jquery метод для этого - `show()`, просто выбираете элемент и вызываете метод `$('ваш_css_селектор').show()`, этот код передаете слушателю событий, к примеру, click по вашему input (см. onclick) по поводу того, чтобы не убиралось - наверное у вас какие-то слушатели событий убирают его или вы используете метод `toggle()`, без вашего кода ничего не понятно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1294609/178988

Answer (score 2):

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 1s linear, border-color 1s step-end;
  transition-delay: 167ms;
  line-height: 2;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10em;
  transition: width 1s linear, border-color 1s step-start;
  transition-delay: 0;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for=inp></label>
<input id=inp>
```

Comment: ♦  `transition-delay: 167ms;` А чем вызвана такая точность задержки?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, упс.. Там при повторном клике по лейблу инпут начинает сужаться и видно анимацию. Задержка нужна чтобы анимация начиналась чуть позже и не успевала до повторного получения фокуса. Когда я это писал, то думал про 1 кадр при 60 fps, но попутал и получилось 10. Сейчас проверил, что при уменьшении до 16.7 не работает)

Comment: ♦ просто удивила такая точность. И это всё равно не решает проблему быстрого повторного клика.  Анимация дергается, возвращается назад. В css анимации есть ли аналог SVG SMIL -- `restart="whenNotActive"`, То есть запрет повторного запуска анимации пока она не закончилась?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, у меня в хроме мигает только подсветка фокуса, ширина не меняется. Про аналог не знаю, но вроде он не должен помочь - иначе инпут свернётся же?

Comment: ♦  Ну почему же свернется? Опять аналог SVG `fill="freeze"` заморозка последнего кадра. В CSS -`forwards`  Да в прочем это всё мелочи. Кто будет-то оч. быстро щелкать по поиску? Щелкнут один раз и будут любоваться, как окошко разворачивается. :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, так тогда навсегда останется открытым. Надо же чтобы он всё-таки свернулся когда из него уйдут. А про очень быстро - я скорее про даблклик вместо обычного думал и про повторный клик (нажал, отвлёкся, вернулся к монитору, нажал ещё раз). А просто так щёлкать если хочется, то анимация как раз в тему ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form')

function setFullWidthControl(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('form__control')) {
    e.target.classList.add('form__control--active')
  }
}

form.addEventListener('click', setFullWidthControl);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  padding: 1em;
}

.form__control {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: .35em 1em;
  transition: width .3s ease;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form__control--active {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <input type="text" class="form__control" placeholder="Enter text">
  <input type="text" class="form__control" placeholder="Enter text">
</form>
```